# Asp.Net MVC Telerik Grid Event After Update

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, telerik, telerik-grid

I was created a project in Asp.Net MVC with telerik.
I am using a telerik grid with editable.
I insert a new record, after this, update this row, then this row will be re-created. It must be updated.

Sample
ADD NEW ->

---

| COMPUTER  |

---

UPDATE THIS with COMPUTER2 ->

---

| COMPUTER  |

---

| COMPUTER2  |

---

this is my .cshtml code

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<Telerik_Test_MVC.Models.CIHAZ_TUR_ViewModel>()
.Name("Grid")
.Columns(columns =>
{
    columns.Bound(p => p.ID).HeaderTemplate("ID").Width(36);
    columns.Bound(p => p.TUR_ADI).HeaderTemplate("CİHAZ TüR ADI").Width(200);
    columns.Command(command => { command.Edit(); command.Destroy(); }).Width(160);
})
.ToolBar(toolbar => toolbar.Create())
.Editable(e => e.Mode(GridEditMode.PopUp))
.Sortable()
 .Resizable(re => re.Columns(true))
 .Groupable()
.DataSource(d => d
    .Ajax()
    .Model(m => m.Id(p => p.ID))
        .Read(u => u.Action("Tur_Read", "Home"))
        .Create(c => c.Action("Tur_Create", "Home"))
        .Destroy(s => s.Action("Tur_Destroy", "Home"))
        .Update(u => u.Action("Tur_Update", "Home"))
)
```

)

these are the create and update methods:

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public ActionResult Tur_Create([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, CIHAZ_TUR_ViewModel product)
    {
        if (product != null && ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            CIHAZ_TUR_DataModel kd = new CIHAZ_TUR_DataModel();
            return Json(kd.Insert(product));
        }
        return Json(new[] { product }.ToDataSourceResult(request, ModelState));
    }

    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public ActionResult Tur_Update([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, CIHAZ_TUR_ViewModel product)
    {
        if (product != null && ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            CIHAZ_TUR_DataModel kd = new CIHAZ_TUR_DataModel();
            return Json(kd.Update(product, product.ID));
        }
        return Json(new[] { product }.ToDataSourceResult(request, ModelState));
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this problem via editing this:

```
product.ID = kd.Insert(product);
```